# Keep original string values after pandas str.extract() if the regex doesn't match

Tags: python, pandas

My input data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['adam','monica','joe doe','michael mo'], 'B':['david','valenti',np.nan,np.nan]})
print(df)
            A        B
0        adam    david
1      monica  valenti
2     joe doe      NaN
3  michael mo      NaN
```

I need to **extract strings after space, to a second column**, but when I use my code...:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].str.extract(r'( [a-zA-Z](.*))')
print(df)
            A     B
0        adam   NaN
1      monica   NaN
2     joe doe   doe
3  michael mo    mo
```

...I receive `NaN` in each cell where value has not been extracted. How to avoid it?
I tried to extract only from rows where NaN exist using this code:

```
df.loc[df.B.isna(),'B'] = df.loc[df.B.isna(),'A'].str.extract(r'( [a-zA-Z](.*))')

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame
```

Expected output:

```
            A     B
0        adam   david
1      monica   valenti
2     joe doe   doe
3  michael mo    mo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think solution should be simplify - split by spaces and get second lists and pass to [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) function:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(df['A'].str.split().str[1])
print (df)
            A        B
0        adam    david
1      monica  valenti
2     joe doe      doe
3  michael mo       mo
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['A'].str.split().str[1])
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    doe
3     mo
Name: A, dtype: object
```

---

Your solution should be changed:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].str.extract(r'( [a-zA-Z](.*))')[0].fillna(df.B)
print (df)
            A        B
0        adam    david
1      monica  valenti
2     joe doe      doe
3  michael mo       mo
```

Better solution wich changed regex and `expand=False` for `Series`:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].str.extract(r'( [a-zA-Z].*)', expand=False).fillna(df.B)
print (df)
            A        B
0        adam    david
1      monica  valenti
2     joe doe      doe
3  michael mo       mo
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['A'].str.extract(r'( [a-zA-Z].*)', expand=False))
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     doe
3      mo
Name: A, dtype: object
```

EDIT:

For extract also values from first column simpliest is use:

```
df1 = df['A'].str.split(expand=True)

df['A'] = df1[0]
df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(df1[1])
print (df)
         A        B
0     adam    david
1   monica  valenti
2      joe      doe
3  michael       mo
```

Comment: thanks, as always ! can i ask you what would be the fastest way to remove extracted string from column A ? should i use something like `df['A'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['A'].replace(x['B'],""))` ?

Comment: @sygneto - yes, it is possible solution, or you can assign values with helper DataFrame after `.split()` - added solution to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't function because of the different shapes of the right and the left sides of your statement. The left part has the shape `(2,)` and the right part `(2, 2)`:

```
df.loc[df.B.isna(),'B']
```

Returns:

```
2    NaN
3    NaN
```

And you want to fill this with:

```
df.loc[df.B.isna(),'A'].str.extract(r'( [a-zA-Z](.*))')
```

Returns:

```
      0   1
2   doe  oe
3    mo   o
```

You can take the column `1` and then it will have the same shape `(2,)` as the left part and will fit:

```
df.loc[df.B.isna(),'A'].str.extract(r'( [a-zA-Z](.*))')[1]
```

Returns:

```
2    oe
3     o
```