# Python Pandas: str.extract removes cell value when no match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get an excel export similar (But a lot bigger) to this:

| Team | Members |
| --- | --- |
| UK-LND-Team A (432) | 685 |
| NZ-CND-Team B (443XC) (001) | 5226 |

I would like to split the "Team" column into two columns, "Team" and "Team ID". Currently I do this with:

```
out = df['Team'].str.extract('(.*) \((\d+)\)$')

df['Team'] = out[0]
df.insert(df.columns.get_loc('Team')+1, 'Team ID', out[1])
```

This works great and returns:

| Team | Team ID | Members |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UK-LND-Team A | 432 | 685 |
| NZ-CND-Team B (443XC) | 001 | 5226 |

But when a team are missing ID the output removes the team name from the Team column, and have both Team and Team ID columns empty. Teams without ID have more limited names (e.g. "NoName", "Unknown Team", "Blank", "--"). As far as I know, they can never have parentheses in them.

Is there any way to catch these events, and make sure that Team column still keeps the team name? The Team ID column can be empty or have the team name in it as well, that does not matter.

It looks to me like the out[0] and out[1] both return NaN with the current setup.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191897/keep-values-after-extract-if-regex-not-fit-pandas

Comment: It might. But if I use `out = df[col].str.extract('(.*) \((\d+)\)$').fillna(df[col])` the entire column gets the same value, and not that spesific cell.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that I found, that works for me. Based one the link Arson shared ([Keep values after extract() if regex not fit. Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191897/keep-values-after-extract-if-regex-not-fit-pandas)):

```
outName = df[col].str.extract('(.*) \((\d+)\)$')[0].fillna(df[col])
outID = df[col].str.extract('(.*) \((\d+)\)$')[1].fillna('')

df[col] = outName
df.insert(df.columns.get_loc(col)+1, col + ' ID', outID)
```

variable name `col` is used instead of `'Team'`

outName: gets the team name, if there is no ID in the name `NaN` is returned, so `fillna(df[col])` replaces it with the original value

outID: gets the team ID, if there is no ID in the name `NaN` is returned, so `fillna('')` replaces it with en emoty string.