# Keep original string values after pandas.series.str.extract() if the regex doesn't match

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract emails from strings, and want to make sure that if the original value is formatted how I expect already, that it is not changed to Nan and instead is kept as is.

Example input

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
1    <doe.b.john@gmail.com>
2    <doe.c.jane@gmail.com>
3    person.anonymous@hotmail.com
4    dent.arthur@space.com
```

I am using

```py
# curr_emails is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
curr_emails = curr_emails.str.extract(r"<([^<>]+)>").squeeze()` # regex extracts text between < >
```

I receive back

```
1    doe.b.john@gmail.com
2    doe.c.jane@gmail.com
3    NaN
4    Nan
```

But I instead would like

```
1    doe.b.john@gmail.com
2    doe.c.jane@gmail.com
3    person.anonymous@hotmail.com
4    dent.arthur@space.com
```

A similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191897/keep-original-string-values-after-pandas-str-extract-if-the-regex-doesnt-matc), but I could not seem to make it work with my current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `<>` pattern, you can fill them by the original value. Or if the `<>` is at the beginning and the end of email, you can just strip them

```py
curr_emails = (curr_emails.str.extract(r"<([^<>]+)>").squeeze()
               .fillna(curr_emails))
# or
curr_emails = curr_emails.str.strip(r'<>')
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, but with `str.extract(r"<([^<>]+)>").fillna(curr_emails).squeeze()`. Im curious, why putting squeeze after fillna resulted it NaNs?

Comment: @CalebRenfroe Couldn't reproduce what you say. But `.str.extract` would return a DataFrame. `DataFrame.fillna(Series)` may work different. `DataFrame.squeeze()` in this example returns a Series.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str.replace` instead of `str.extract` to replace `<` at the start of a string or `>` at the end of a string with `''`

```
curr_emails.str.replace('^<|>$', '', regex=True)

0            doe.b.john@gmail.com
1            doe.c.jane@gmail.com
2    person.anonymous@hotmail.com
3           dent.arthur@space.com
```

Comment: This solution worked, but only for the current case I described above. I could also have long strings, such as `Doe, John PGM GUY FOOBARINC MD (USA) <john.doe@email.mail>` and in which case this fails to extract what I want. Apologize for not being clear on all my cases.